# Splitting of bash variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, string

We have cgi application written in bash scripts. I am trying to understand how the code snippet below works. Basically its a dropdown menu and the choices is governed by _getDocType logic. How does the function take the value for "imgCodeStr"? All of this code is under one cgi file written in bash.

HTML generating function

```
<select id="docType" name="doctype" style="width:100%">
        $(_getDocType)
</select>
```

where _getDocType function definition is

```bash
_getDocType()
{
        tmpIfs=IFS
        IFS="#" docCodeArr=($imgCodeStr) <-- Please explain this specifically
        IFS=tmpIfs

        for (( i=0; i<${#docCodeArr[*]}; i++ ))
        do
                echo "<option value=\"${docCodeArr[$i]}\">${docCodeArr[$i]}"
                echo "</option>"
        done
}
```

Comment: Note that there's a bug: `tmpIfs=IFS` and `IFS=tmpIfs` should be `tmpIfs=$IFS` and `IFS=$tmpIfs`. This would bite you if the rest of the script relied on the value of `IFS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler example:

```
var='a#b#c'
IFS=\# arr=($var)
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

The construct `arr=(...)` builds an array.  Since `IFS` is set to `#`, the value of `var` is split into words at `#` instead of spaces, so

```
IFS=\# arr=($var)
```

is equivalent to

```
arr=(a b c)
```

Thus the array `arr` is formed of elements `a`, `b`, and `c`.

For the same reason, `docCodeArr` is an array, made of the value of `imgCodeStr` split at `#`.  That's about all there is to it.

Beware that if the value of `imgCodeStr` contains wildcard characters (characters among `\[?*`), the shell will expand the wildcard pattern to matching file names. To avoid this, put `set -f` before that line to disable wildcard expansion. If you need to reenable wildcard expansion, use `set +f`.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation. I have a follow up question. In the for loop section, the second argument is a limit where i is lesser than doccodearr array. Can you explain a bit how the length of this array was derived?

Comment: @dimas `${#docCodeArr[*]}` is the length of the array.  You can read all about `bash` arrays in `man bash`.